# How to derive a key from an existing AES key?

Tags: aes, reference-request, key-derivation

Currently, the code I am staring at uses the `CKM_EXTRACT_KEY_FROM_KEY` mechanism.  That has been disabled in our hardware module, so I need a different mechanism to derive a new key from an existing aes key.  I don't want to change too much code as I don't know what the ramifications will be.  I could use `C_CopyObject`, but that is no more secure that the mechanism it would replace, from my very limited understanding of crypto stuff.

What alternatives exist to derive a key from an existing AES key?

Comment: HKDF. Or similar KBKDFs.

Comment: I presume you are limited to PKCS#11 ? Which version? 2.20?

Comment: What is the purpose of deriving a new key? I.e. what are the old and new keys used for?

Comment: v 2.20, yes.  They are single purpose keys - we create a key with the derive attribute set, then use that to create new keys with wrap, encrypt, decrypt, etc. attributes.